# jQuery html response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-cache

Is it possible to determine if a **response** returned by **$.ajax** was served from the browser's cache or was fresh?

Thanks.

Comment: change your title to reflect what you are asking more clearly, e.g.  "Determining if jQuery html response was cached or fresh"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. What you can do is to create a new URL every time (eg: by appending a random string to the URL, which is ignored by the script on the server), or by setting the response's cache headers appropriately.

See: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL

You might want to set `max-age`, `no-store`, `no-cache`, `must-revalidate` or a combination of the previous.

Comment: Also, the img tag has a `complete` property to indicate whether or not the browser has loaded a particular image. http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/image.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in jQuery to make sure it does not cache:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false}});
```

Am not sure what you are looking to achieve.

If you really want to know if the data is stale, you can do something like:

1. Make your server written return a unique string each and every time it is called
2. Check if this string exists in your javascript temp variables
3. If yes, its stale, if no, its new.

Comment: I don't want to modify the request. I just want to know after receiving some response from server (not necessarily mine) using AJAX if the response was cached or fresh.